# Is there an analytical way to find the area under the probability density function of a stable distribution over a particular interval I=[a,b]

Tags: integral, heavy-tailed, stable-distribution

I am trying to find the area over the interval I=[a,b] for a stable distribution. As you know, in general, the densities of stable laws do not have explicit expressions via elementary functions. Therefore, finding the area over an integral I might be difficult. Is there a trick or a way to overcome this difficulty?

I understand that properties of stable distributions are investigated indirectly, often by using the integral transformations such as Laplacian and Fourier transformation. Can someone refer me to papers or books that answer my question?

Comment: I'm not sure, but my guess is 'not analytically, but probably fairly well numerically'. I know that the characteristic functions of stable distributions have particularly simple forms (especially when symmetric). There's a freely available book I've glanced through that seemed like a really good introduction to stable distributions [here](http://fs2.american.edu/jpnolan/www/stable/chap1.pdf). I'd imagine if it's possible to compute such an integral, it would be included in an introductory book on the subject.

Comment: Actually, I should just post the page that book came from: http://fs2.american.edu/jpnolan/www/stable/stable.html.

Comment: @Will the links do not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research, I am grateful to Professor John Nolan for his time in answering this question, and I thought of sharing this information.

There is no "closed form" solution to such integrals. Therefore, to get the area under such an interval one can only achieve this by numerical integration.